# Cygwin: Perl script $ENV{PATH} call returns unix path. How do I change it?

Tags: perl, bash, path, cygwin

I am calling a Perl script from cygwin. The issue that I am having is that when it calls $ENV{PATH}, the path is receives is a unix path. How do I change my shell so it returns a DOS path?

Comment: what does `change my shell` mean? where is it that you think you need a DOS path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin is a Unix-emulation environment for Windows. It wouldn't work unless `$PATH` was a Unix-style path.

If you want `perl` to give you a DOS path, use a DOS-compatible Perl, like [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). You can even run Strawberry Perl (or whatever Windows-build of `perl` you use) from Cygwin if you want to.

Comment: No, that's not right. I want to use Cygwin Perl (because it is only that does non-blocking IO correctly), but I also want it to interact with non-Cygwin programs. Since Cygwin is only emulation it should be friendly to both systems. There should be some envvar to setup this (I suspect no such var exists).

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the shell, so changing shell won't help, and there's nothing you can change in the shell to help.

```
>echo %PATH% & perl -E"say $ENV{PATH}"
c:\progs\cygwin\bin;...;C:\Windows\system32;...
/usr/bin:...:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:...
```

The purpose of cygwin is to allow unix program to be compiled on a Windows machine with as little changes as possible, which means the system calls must behave as if the program was executing on a unix machine, which means the PATH must look like a unix path.

If you had used a Windows build of Perl (such as ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl), you wouldn't have this problem.

If you wish to continue using a Cygwin build of Perl, you could use the Cygwin tool `cygpath` to convert the paths for you.

```
$ perl -E'
    my $cmd = q{IFS=: ; cygpath -w $PATH};
    chomp( my @paths = `$cmd` );
    say for @paths;
'
C:\progs\cygwin\home\ikegami\usr\perlbrew\bin
.
C:\progs\cygwin\home\ikegami\bin
C:\progs\cygwin\usr\local\bin
C:\progs\cygwin\bin
C:\progs\perl5163-ap1603\site\bin
C:\progs\perl5163-ap1603\bin
C:\bin
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
...
```

Comment: How to do it Perl-way? I mean without any external executions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cygpath` and call bash with: (Looks like you have to set IFS.)

```
` IFS=:; cygpath --windows \$PATH`
```

Or unsetting IFS.

```
`IFS=;cygpath --windows --path \$PATH`
```

Or you could just do it with a few simple rules.

```
map { 
    # turn cygdrives to drive letter + colon
    s!^/cygdrive/(\w)/!\U$1:!;   

    # locate the cygwin relative paths to whatever it is on your system.
    s!^/!$CYGWIN_HOME/!;

    $_ = qq("$_") if m/[() ]/; # quote paths where necessary

    # You don't really need to switch the slashes for perl, Java
    # a lot of other multi-platform tools.
    s!/!\\!g;
} split /:/, $ENV{PATH}
;
```

Note that you might have to expand the character set in the match expression.

Comment: @ikegami works fine from bash. I just cut and pasted it into my bash terminal. Where I got it.

Comment: The final solution is incomplete. What's `$CYGWIN_HOME`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, although maybe a bit late :)

Copy the PATH to a Cygwin-unrecognised variable and use that instead:

```
set MYPATH=%PATH%
perl -e 'print join("\n",split(";",$ENV{MYPATH}),"\n")'
```