# Why is opendir argument invalid?

Tags: perl

```
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 1 (v5.30.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
Win10
cygwin
```

I can't figure out how to use opendir. Here is my example code:

```
sub test($) {
   my $dir     = shift;
   opendir (DIR, $dir) || die "Couldn't open dir $dir $!";
}
sub main() {
   my $dir = `pwd`;
   test($dir);
}
```

Error message

```
Couldn't open dir /home/skidmarks/Projects/Perl
 Invalid argument at ./test.py line .
```

pwd returns a unix formatted directory path ('/'). I have tried it with a windows formatted directory path ('\'). The only thing that works is to use a literal string for the path, e.g., "." or "some_directory_path".

Can't I use a variable in opendir for the path?

Comment: The `pwd` you are running is from Cygwin, which is a unix emulation. You then take the path it returns and try to use it in Windows. That's not going to work, even if you remove the line feed!

Comment: As this runs with `cygwin` the paths will be different as @ikegami says.  One solution is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21920871/4653379)

Comment: @zdim Cygwin's `pwd`, but a Windows Perl

Comment: @ikegami right, thank you, edited the comment

Answer (score 6):

The [qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) (backticks) returns the newline as well, so you need `chomp $dir;`.

Better yet, why not use Perl's facilities

```
use Cwd qw(cwd);

my $dir = cwd;
```

and now you don't have to worry about system commands and how exactly they return.

---

As the OP uses `pwd` from `cygwin`, even once the linefeed is gone the obtained path is unix-style and this conflicts with MSWin32 build of Perl (as reported when opening the file). Using a portable tool (like `Cwd` above) and a Windows build of Perl should avoid such problems.

Or use a tool to convert paths, like `cygpath`.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917495/cygwin-perl-script-envpath-call-returns-unix-path-how-do-i-change-it)

Comment: Fixed the issue with argument failure, but now can't find the directory. Error "Couldn't open dir D:/home/skidmarks/Projects/Perl No such file or directory at ./test.py line 36.". Change in main to omy $dir = cwd. The more general comment is that I need the ability to open any directory, not just the cwd.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez Alright.  Now that's a matter of your filesystem -- apparently a directory with that name doesn't exist.  The code you have will open a given `$dir` if it exists.  I didn't understand how you meant to open a `/home/...` path in Windows? Do you really have access to such paths in Windows?

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez  And as this is under `cygwin` paths are given in unix style, as @ikegami says, and you've got to do a little more. A quick seach yields for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21920871/4653379).  Added to the answer

Comment: /home/ issue is because I was dropped on my head as a child. In (all) of my filesystems I create a directory called '/home'. All of my active projects are rooted at '/home/' something. In this case, /home/skidmarks/projects/perl'. No mystery; just confusion. I have elected to not put /home into the cygwin root directory '/'.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez  Ah, that.  (Same here I think ... they never admitted it but I have my reasons to believe it happened :).   I think that that's good, to have a "canonical" (for you) structure across various environments; I always have a "home" folder under Windows, in the user account (not desktop). With Cygwin it apparently only takes that little extra work, when (the actual) system paths matter

Answer (score 1):

Try following piece of code, it works well with [Strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

Also try to put **full path** in double quotes `"c:\Program Files\Common Files"`.

If directory name is not provided then the script will list **current** directory

Usage: `perl script.pl "C:\Users\User_name"`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $dir_name = shift || '.';

opendir(my $dir, $dir_name)
    or die "Couldn't open $dir_name";

map{ say } readdir($dir);

closedir $dir;
```

NOTE: Navigate in Cygwin terminal to *target* directory and issue command `pwd`. Perl script run in Cygwin perhaps will expect the **path** in this form.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of **Cygwin** was installed and tested with slightly modified code -- works fine.

NOTE: `pwd` is Linux/UNIX command which produces an error in MS Windows, but works in Cygwin which emulates Linux/UNIX environment (binary incompatible, requires recompilation of the programs)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

sub test($) {
   my $dir = shift;

   opendir(my $dh, $dir)
        or die "Couldn't open dir $dir $!";

   map{ say } readdir($dh);

   close $dh;
}

sub main() {
   my $dir = `pwd`;
   chomp $dir;

   print "[$dir]\n";

   test($dir);
}

main();
```

Function main is not required in perl (main() function is C/C++ entrance point) and normally code looks like following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $dir = `pwd`;          # pwd is UNIX/Linux command will give an error in MS Windows

chomp $dir;               # trim \n at the end of $dir

say "DIRECTORY: [$dir]";  # Let's check what we got

test($dir);

sub test {
   my $dir = shift;

   opendir(my $dh, $dir)
        or die "Couldn't open dir $dir $!";

   map{ say } readdir($dh);

   close $dh;
}
```